# Parallel execution with own iterator

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, c++17, std

I have some simple code which check big number primality by finding dividers. I try to do it in parallel by using `std::none_of` function with parallel execution policy:

```
BigInt isPrime(const BigInt &x) {
  BigInt i(0);
  BigIntRangeIterator range(2, x);
// If use std::vector, works fine:
// std::vector<BigInt> range;
// for (BigInt i(2); i < x; i = i + BigInt(1)) range.push_back(i);
  std::mutex m;
  std::none_of(std::execution::par_unseq, range.begin(), range.end()
              , [&](auto y) {
                  if (x % y == BigInt(0)) {
                    const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
                    i = y;
                    return true;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
  );
  return i;
}
```

Function `isPrime` returns zero, if number is prime, otherwise it returns any divider of x.

For not to waste space for storing range of dividers, I implement own iterator for `BigNum`, which stores just begin, end and current value, and increment it:

```
/* Header file */
class BigIntRangeIterator
    : public std::iterator
    < std::forward_iterator_tag
    , BigInt
    , BigInt
    , const BigInt*
    , BigInt&
    >
{
  public:
    BigIntRangeIterator(): _begin(0), _end(0), _it(0){}
    BigIntRangeIterator(const BigInt &b, const BigInt &e)
      : _begin(b), _end(e), _it(b) {}

    bool operator!=(const BigIntRangeIterator &rhs) const;
    bool operator==(const BigIntRangeIterator &rhs) const;
    BigInt const & operator*() const;
    BigIntRangeIterator const & operator++();
    BigIntRangeIterator begin() const;
    BigIntRangeIterator end() const;

  private:
    BigInt _begin, _end, _it;
};
```

```
/*CPP file */
bool BigIntRangeIterator::operator!=(const BigIntRangeIterator &rhs) const {
  return _it != rhs._it;
}

bool BigIntRangeIterator::operator==(const BigIntRangeIterator &rhs) const {
  return _it == rhs._it;
}

BigInt const & BigIntRangeIterator::operator*() const {
  return _it;
}

BigIntRangeIterator const & BigIntRangeIterator::operator++() {
  _it = _it + BigInt(1);
  return *this;
}

BigIntRangeIterator BigIntRangeIterator::begin() const {
  return BigIntRangeIterator(_begin, _end);
}

BigIntRangeIterator BigIntRangeIterator::end() const {
  BigIntRangeIterator ret(_begin, _end);
  ret._it = _end;
  return ret;
}
```

My problem is, that this function always runs in one thread, ignoring parallel execution policy. Why does it do it?

Comment: @Jarod42, code updated, but it did not resolve problem

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @ypnos, gcc 9.3.1, function `none_of` works fine in parallel on std vectors

Comment: You could try it with TBB, as gcc parallel std normally uses TBB backend. Might give you insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long searching I found, that `none_of` function with parallel execution policy works parallel only with random access iterator. If own iterator is just forward iterator, it always will run sequentially.